# Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample error

Tags: python, node.js

i'm trying to use python in my node.js project using npm python shell, my python script aims to hierarchically cluster a dataset using sklearn library. i send the dataset as a 2d array to the python script but i get this weird error

Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample error.

the error message also states:

```
 ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:\r\n
array=0.593934222,0.249954941,0.213356151,0.128768518,0.597381076,0.191858507,0.578032151,0.572388127,0.32216372,0.524071895,0.248102058,0.190557532,0.110445891,0.310592749,0.609993217,0.384038873,0.751802054,0.769711062,0.761773915,0.34313952,0.269207149,0.154800021,0.51600189,0.215849563,0.931827523,0.380445861,0.155714978,0.855579232,0.396393924,0.236950661,0.145275841,0.249733315,0.858764558,0.61553417,0.752858691,0.545378696,0.40406226,0.203121647,0.195151239,0.109380912,0.496808461,0.145746866,0.220833125,0.246972535,0.576208892.\r\n
```

i googled it and it seems that this error occurs when you send in a 1d array, even though i'm sending a 2d array.

here's the python code

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

X = np.array(sys.argv[1])

cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=sys.argv[2], affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')
cluster.fit_predict(X)
```

here is the node js code where the python script is called, i'm just trying to make it work for now so there aren't many details

```
app.post("/route", (req, res) => {
    let dataset=req.body.data;
    let clustNum=req.body.clustNum;
    let options = {
        args: [dataset,clustNum]
      };

    PythonShell.run('./hclust.py', options, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('finished');
      });
    res.send("done")
})
```

here's an example of how my data arrays look like:

```
[

[

0.593934222, 0.249954941,

0.213356151, 0.128768518,

0.597381076, 0.191858507,

0.578032151, 0.572388127,

0.32216372

],

[

0.524071895, 0.248102058,

0.190557532, 0.110445891,

0.310592749, 0.609993217,

0.384038873, 0.751802054,

0.769711062

],

[

0.761773915, 0.34313952,

0.269207149, 0.154800021,

0.51600189, 0.215849563,

0.931827523, 0.380445861,

0.155714978

],

[

0.855579232, 0.396393924,

0.236950661, 0.145275841,

0.249733315, 0.858764558,

0.61553417, 0.752858691,

0.545378696

],

[

0.40406226, 0.203121647,

0.195151239, 0.109380912,

0.496808461, 0.145746866,

0.220833125, 0.246972535,

0.576208892

]

]
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What exact error are you seeing? Can you reproduce this problem without the node stuff? If so, you can remove all the node stuff from the discussion as it distracts from your real issue.
========
Guess: you need to convert sys.argv[2] from a string into an integer, e.g. `n_clusters=int(sys.argv[2])`.

Comment: well when i tried the exact same code with the same array above using pure python it worked with no problems, so i think there is a problem in passing args between node and python shell